# jquery on working on php result button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax script , i am using this script for show result in php, In result i am printing button & now i want to use jquery method on this button, But jquery is not working.

My ajax code is below

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo base_url('/map/connection_list/')?>",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "HTML",

    success: function(data)
    {   

        $("#res").html(data);
        //$("#content").html(data.content);
       // $('[id="content"]').val(data.content);

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
});

$("#yes").click(function(){
   alert("ok");
 });
 });
```

result with php code is below

```
    <button id='yes' class='btn btn-primary'>Yes</button>
    <button id='no' class='btn btn-default'>No</button>
```

Now i want to use jquery function on this button as i used in below function for alert . $('#yes')click(function(){
alert("ok");
});
this function is not working.

Comment: `$("#yes").click(function({//ajax here}))`

Comment: Are the buttons inside a form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var fireAjax = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('/map/connection_list/')?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "HTML",

        success: function (data) {

            $("#res").html(data);
            //$("#content").html(data.content);
            // $('[id="content"]').val(data.content);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
};

$("#yes").click(fireAjax);
$("#no").click(function () { /* Do sth. else */ });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

> $('body').on('click', '#yes', function(){ alert('tes'); });

I'm on mobile, hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Today, I was on mobile so my code was not clear for you I think. This is how you can handle this thing!

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo base_url('/map/connection_list/')?>',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#res').html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });

    $('body').on('click','#yes',function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your code check [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqrMk/4045/).To make ajax request using jQuery you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#yes").click(function() {
  alert("OK");
  $.ajax({ //Process the request using $.ajax()
   url: "<?php echo base_url('/map/connection_list/')?>",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "HTML",

   success: function(data) {

    $("#res").html(data);
    //$("#content").html(data.content);
    // $('[id="content"]').val(data.content);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error get data from ajax');
   }

  });
 });
});
```

Comment: but after ajax result i will get button with yes id, so how can i create function before result?